# Pointer argument from double to double*

Tags: c++, function, pointers, void

I made a very basic program to try to better understand pointers but I cannot figure them out. I continue to get the error *'void celsius(double *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'double *'*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void celsius(double*);

int main() {

    double temp;
    double value;

    cout << "Enter temperature in C ";
    cin >> value;

    temp = celsius(value);

    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;
}

void celsius(double *par) {
double tem;

tem = (1.8 * par + 32);
    return tem;
}
```

After referring to several resources I just cant figure out why it's returning the error. I know the error says it's because it can't convert a double to double* but examples I see online don't explain why.

Any help with the code or explanation be great. Thanks.

Comment: You umust take the address of `value` to pass it into a function expecting a pointer. Eg: `temp = celsius(&value);` Note: this will reveal other problems.

Comment: Just change `void celsius(double*)` to `double celsius(double)`.  There is no reason the function needs a pointer.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `void celsuis(...` also should be changed to `double celsius(...` as you are returning a `double`

Comment: I recommend exploring *references* before pointers.  For example, declare `void celsius(double& variable)`.  When passing by reference, the function knows that the parameter exists.  When passing a pointer, the point may point to anywhere, including not the variable from the caller.  Much safer to use references.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the following changes to your program.

1. Change the return type of the function to `double`.

   ```
   double celsius(double*);
   ```
2. When you call the function, make sure you pass a pointer to a `double`, not a `double`.

   ```
   temp = celsius(&value);  // Use &value, not value
   ```
3. In the function, you need to use `*par` to dereference the pointer and use its value.

   ```
   tem = (1.8 * (*par) + 32);  // Use *par not just par
   ```

---

Another option is to leave the return type as is but change the implementation of the function.

```
void celsius(double *par)
{
   *par = (1.8 * (*par) + 32);
}
```

and change the usage to just

```
celsius(&value);
cout << value << endl;
```

Comment: Why not just suggest changing `void celsius(double*)` to `double celsius(double)`?  It is one change instead of 3.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I did not want to change the OP's motivation - *try to better understand pointers*

Comment: Ah, in that case `void celsius(double *par) { *par = (1.8 * (*par) + 32) }` and `celsius(value); cout << value << endl;` would showcase that more.

Comment: @NathanOliver, that's also an option too. Thanks :)

Comment: Appreciate the help! This helps me understand it a lot more. Part of the issue was looking at so many different examples and not seeing what pieced together. But these examples really demonstrate it well :)

Answer (score 0):

I’m sure this has been said a billion times but think of the pointer variable as just a variable.

double* is simply a type and on 32 not machines it can hold 4 Byte values. On 64 not machines there is a bigger addressing space so pointers are bigger.

Then, if double* is just a variable that can store a 4 byte address of a double then it needs the address of something...

You can take the address of other variables using ‘&’

Example:

```
double* ptr = &anotherVariable;
```

Now ‘ptr’ contains a 4 byte address and then you can access the variable contents by dereferencing the double pointer itself.

Example:

```
*ptr = 4.2;
```

However, the ‘ptr’ variable itself contains an address so the ‘anotherVariable’ that was assigned to it earlier also has the value 4.2

Now, if you were passing a value to a function and the functions parameter was ‘double* temp’. You could pass it the address of a variable or an actual pointer and inside the function you can do all the same things as above.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective on how these work, this is very helpful with my understanding. Really appreciate.